# Cannot access docker container from docker host

Tags: linux, docker, networking, containers, firewall

**Situation**

I am running a Debian based docker host server machine with docker containers. The containers are configured using a defined docker network and have assigned a static ip address. I want to access each container by its own IP address. The network is configured to share the IP address range of the hosts.

> ```
> Network:      192.168.178.0/24
> Host IP:      192.168.178.100
> Router IP:    192.168.178.1
> Container IP: 192.168.178.140
> ```

The docker network was created by:

> ```
> docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.178.0/24 --gateway=192.168.178.1 -o parent=eno0 dockernet
> ```

The containers are using the same docker network and are configured by using docker-compose:

> ```
>  gitlab:
>     image: gitlab/gitlab-ce
>     restart: always
>     networks:
>         dockernet:
>             ipv4_address: 192.168.178.140
>     dns:
>         - 192.168.178.102
>         - 8.8.8.8
>         - 4.4.4.4
>     ports:
>         - 80:80
>         - 443:443
>         - 22:22
> ```

**Problem**

Now from any computer in the same network I could ping the docker container, but not from the host itself. I thought that could be a firewall issue, but could not confirm (by deleting all firewall rules).

**Current IP tables configuration:**

> ```
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
> DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
> DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
> DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
>
> Chain DOCKER (1 references)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
>
> Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
> DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
> RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
>
> Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
> DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
> RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
>
> Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
> target     prot opt source               destination         
> RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
> ```

Also checked Debian hosts.deny - it is empty.

**Execute ping on docker host machine:**

> ```
> $ping 192.168.178.140
> PING 192.168.178.140 (192.168.178.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
> From 192.168.178.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
> ```

**Execute ping from any other computer:**

> ```
> $ping 192.168.178.140
> PING 192.168.178.140 (192.168.178.140): 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from 192.168.178.140: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.189 ms
> 64 bytes from 192.168.178.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.965 ms
> ```

**Questions:**

1. Any idea regarding the firewall rules, etc.?
2. Any other idea of how to configure the docker network to have static IPs for the containers?
3. Any other thought on this why I can't access my docker containers from the docker host?

Comment: Typical Docker use is to publish a port for each service you’re running and access them via the host’s DNS name or IP address.  Would this work for your broader use case?

Comment: No, not really. I would like to have separate IP addresses for the services.